# Dicing in python

Tags: python

Code:-

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':t, 'col2':wordList})
df.columns=['DNT','tweets']
df.DNT = pd.to_datetime(df.DNT, errors='coerce')
check=df[ (df.DNT < '09:20:00') & (df.DNT > '09:00:00') ]
```

Don't know why this code is not working.
Does anyone know what is wrong in the above code?

Comment: Are you are using > and < to compare strings? It doesn't sound rigth to me.

Comment: I am using '>','<' these to compare dates.

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: '09:20:00' is a string not a datetime object

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831410/python-time-comparison

Comment: you just want to compare with the time '09:20:00' or including date like '2017-05-26 09:20:00'?

Comment: Just Time :) and nothing else.

Comment: what's your `t(DNT)` in your code?

Comment: t= 2017-05-24 09:06:11
    2017-05-24 09:06:12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare with `datetime` format like this:

Suppose:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['2017-05-24 09:06:11','2017-05-24 09:06:12','2017-05-24 09:00:00'], 'col2':['hello','hi','bonjour']})
df.columns=['DNT','tweets']
df.DNT = pd.to_datetime(df.DNT, errors='coerce')
df
```

`df` will be:

```
    DNT                  tweets
0   2017-05-24 09:06:11  hello
1   2017-05-24 09:06:12  hi
2   2017-05-24 09:00:00  bonjour
```

Then you can compare with `start` and `end`:

```
end = datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 24, 9, 20) #2017-05-24 09:20:00
start = datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 24, 9) #2017-05-24 09:00:00
df[ (df.DNT < end) & (df.DNT > start) ]
```

Then filter result will be:

```
    DNT                  tweets
0   2017-05-24 09:06:11  hello
1   2017-05-24 09:06:12  hi
```

Comment: glad it helps :), u need practice more, coding more, then u will rock it :)

Comment: Hey @Tiny.D 
I want to convert the words into dense vectors so that I can use them in neural networks. Words(example)
'automotive', 'auto', 'ebc', 'greenstuff', '6000', 'series', 'supreme', 'truck', 'and', 'suv', 'brake', 'pads', 'dp61603' 
Could you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: you can split the sentence string with split(), it will return a list which contain all words.

Comment: Actually I wanted to know how can I convert these words into vectors ?

Comment: ok, please raise a question with details (your requirement, your expected result, etc), then let me know.

Comment: Here is the link for the question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44236021/converting-list-of-strings-into-vector-form)

Comment: you'd better know how to ask question, not like that, with example data input will be better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145342/discussion-between-tiny-d-and-vic13).